# apache-camel Scheduler component exchange property TIMER_NAME empty

Tags: apache-camel

I am developing an apache camel route like this

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    from("scheduler:intervalo?initialDelay=1000&delay=10000")
        .setProperty("test",simple("valueTest1"))
        .log("v1 ->${exchangeProperty.TIMER_NAME}<-")
        .log("v2 ->${exchangeProperty.TIMER_FIRED_TIME}<-")
        .log("v3 ->${exchangeProperty.test}<-")         
    .end();
}//configure
```

I am expecting the TIMER_NAME and TIMER_FIRED_TIME exchange properties to be filled with the name and time the consumer was fired. This is explained in the component documentation [here](http://camel.apache.org/scheduler.html).

But the log shows nothing

```
[ead #2 - scheduler://intervalo] route1                         INFO  v1 -><-
[ead #2 - scheduler://intervalo] route1                         INFO  v2 -><-
[ead #2 - scheduler://intervalo] route1                         INFO  v3 ->valueTest1<-
```

The test property has been added to check if I was making a syntax or similar error.

Why are TIME_NAME and TIMER_FIRED_TIME not filled? I think I am doing something wrong with the syntax or the name, but I can not find it.

Thank you ver much in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the wrong name for those, as they are constants defined on the `Exchange` interface, then their values are

- String TIMER_NAME            = "CamelTimerName";
- String TIMER_FIRED_TIME      = "CamelTimerFiredTime";

So use `CamelTimerName` in the logging. Also you can use tracer to see what goes on instead of adding log's yourself: http://camel.apache.org/tracer

Comment: `.log("${exchangeProperty[CamelTimerFiredTime]}")   .log("${exchangeProperty[CamelTimerName]}")` works perfectly. But I am now wondering if there is a way to use not the actual value of the constant but the name of the variable. Something `${exchange. ...}` I have been reading the [simple documentation](http://camel.apache.org/simple.html) but I do not quite understand the exchange or type part.